# Dealing with Int32.MinValue and NULL when executing Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: .net, oracle, c#-4.0

I believe this is a pretty simple question but am looking for a 'best practice' answer.
I am setting up a call in C# .Net to an Oracle stored procedure.  The stored procedure is set to accept all NUMBER type arguments.  Since Oracle allows setting these values to NULL the current stored procedure is checking for `IS NOT NULL`.  Pretty straightforward.  The issue is that the .Net code cannot set an `int` field to `DBNull.Value`, so instead `Int32.MinValue` is used.  This discrepancy is causing issues for the stored procedure checks.  I have asked the developer to check for `0` in the stored procedure but am wondering if there is a better way to deal with this?  It seems that it should check for both `NULL` and `0` since the concept of a minimum value does not exist in Oracle.  Is this the best manner of dealing with this?
Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that the .Net code cannot set an int field to DBNull.Value, so instead Int32.MinValue is used.

Don't do that. Use `Nullable<int>` (aka `int?`) instead, which *can* have a null value.

It's not really clear *where* you're doing any of this, but there's no need to use magic values to represent nullity.